# Restrict app hanging when sending/receiving mysql data

Tags: c#, mysql

Ok so recently I've using MySQL to transfer data between client and server form a game that I've developing. The game is a hacking-simulation type of game. The problem I'm facing is that, while sending data or receiving data, the app hangs for a couple seconds. I've seen or played other games which use MySQL but he never hang or stop working for few seconds. As I move on thinking about it, it would definitely feel weird when a user presses an 'Attack' button, the app hangs for few seconds and then when he presses to move forward it hangs for couple more seconds and so on.
How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You need to do long-running stuff on another thread so it doesn't affect the UI.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the answer?

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment, and I can't really think of a way to say it more plainly.  You need to put the stuff that's causing your delays onto another thread.  Google it.

Comment: Yeah. What he said. You get it implicitly if you use async/await constructs when doing queries. Like so: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819165(v=vs.113).aspx